# Rewrite URL with subdirectory and file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i am trying to use .htaccess to rewrite the URLs for my site, here is what i would like

currently, the urls look like this

```
http://www.mysite.biz/store/cart.php?m=new_arrivals
```

All of the sites are loaded using php GET and the only thing that ever changes is the query string after cart.php so i would like to rewrite to....

```
http://www.mysite.biz/cart.php?m=new_arrivals
```

I have been searching all over the internet and have tried out various techniques to do this and none of them have worked.  i've tried this...

```
RewriteRule ^store/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.biz/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/store($|/)
RewriteRule ^.*$ /store/cart.php [L]
```

and this...

```
RewriteCond $1 !^store
RewriteRule ^(.*) /store/$1 [L]
```

ive been developing web for a while now but this is my first time really doing anything with .htaccess and i am totally stumped. any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+store/(cart\.php[^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^(cart\.php)$ /store/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: ok, i just tried that and it didnt work. i had some other stuff in the .htaccess but i commented everything out except for your line and it still didnt work...

Comment: Are you expecting external redirect from `http://www.mysite.biz/store/cart.php?m=new_arrivals` to `http://www.mysite.biz/cart.php?m=new_arrivals`?

Comment: i add your code to my .htaccess file, i ftp it to the root of my site, and i go to different pages on my site.  the /store/cart.php stays in the url for both pieces of code you provided

Comment: Are you sure .htaccess and mod_rewrite are enabled?

Comment: yes, i have other rewrite rules in there and they work fine. i commented them out when testing and it still didnt work

Comment: Well there is something not right in your local setup. I rested `/store/cart.php?m=new_arrivals` and it became `/cart.php?m=new_arrivals`

Comment: ok thanks for your help, maybe hosting company is doing something ill talk to them